# 301 Redirects from http to https and non-www to www causing severe server slowdowns

Tags: .htaccess

My `htaccess` file looks like this:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteCond %{HTTP_USER_AGENT} ^(.+)$
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^website\.co\.uk$ [OR]
RewriteCond %{SERVER_NAME} ^x1l\.111\.myftpupload\.com$
RewriteRule .* https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
Header add Strict-Transport-Security "max-age=300"
Header always set Content-Security-Policy "upgrade-insecure-requests"
</IfModule>
```

My problem is that the 301 redirect is causing significant slowdown in terms of the load speeds (at 20s+ sometimes, and even timing out from time to time). However, when I use the www-version, everything seems to be working fine and pages are loading significantly quicker.

I've tried everything I know to no avail.

I'm sure I'm missing something and would love to take a step in the right direction. Would appreciate some guidance!

Comment: You do not have a `non-www` to `www` rule in the  htaccess you posted.

Comment: Hi Amit,, I'm quite new to htaccess and don't really know how to navigate just yet. I researched about the 301 error and only learned about it from there. Here's a [gtmetrix report](https://gtmetrix.com/reports/kaizenadvisory.co.uk/mIkqTqbD/) which shows the 301 redirects (http to https then non-www to www) in the waterfall chart. Would appreciate your wisdom on this!